# Multiplying objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm doing java script tutorial and i encountered weird piece of code which for the guy doing tutorial work but not for me. And i know why, but i can't figure out why it works for him. He tried and multiplied two objects which i know it can't be done.
Can someone explain me why the following code works for him because result of it, gives me NaN which is normal because it is not a number it's object.

```
        tool.onKeyDown = function(event) {
                var maxPoint = new Point (view.size.width, view.size.height); 
                //Gives screen width {x:600, y:300}
                var randomPoint = new Point.random();
                //Gives random betwen 0-1 {x:.5, y:0.5}
                var point = maxPoint * randomPoint; //multiplying gives him {300,150}
                console.log(point) // NAN
                new Path.Circle(point, 20).fillColor = "orange";
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a new point with the new values:

Multiplication works only with numbers, not with objects. If you need to multiply points, then you have to implement that as an own method of `Point`.

```
tool.onKeyDown = function(event) {
    var maxPoint = new Point (view.size.width, view.size.height); 
    //Gives screen width {x:600, y:300}
    var randomPoint = new Point.random();
    //Gives random betwen 0-1 {x:.5, y:0.5}
    var point = new Point(maxPoint.x * randomPoint.x, maxPoint.y * randomPoint.y); // gives him {x: 300, y: 150}
    console.log(point) // should return correct result
    new Path.Circle(point, 20).fillColor = "orange";
}
```

Edit

It works in the example with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="paper-full.js"></script>
```

and a script block with `type="text/paperscript"`

```
<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">
// code here
</script>
```

Comment: Already did it, i solved the puzzle, my problem is why does it work for him.
I'm now under impression that I'm missing some part of java script.

Comment: please add some more information about your used tutorial.

Comment: It's Udemy tutorial. Patatap Clone,  the code provided is what he does, essentially and the math he provided i did what you just showed me and it works fine, but my problem is that someone managed to multiply two objects and for the life of me i can't figure out how. I don't like the feeling not knowing how it works.

Comment: can you provide the reference link of tutorial which you mention ..?? because  @nina is right multiplication work with number.

Comment: I wrote same thing, multiplying works with numbers not objects. It's video tutorial and code snippet is one i wrote above. I'm giving you all the tools in my code, thats it from the code. Nothing else. I'm stunned that he managed to do it with that same code

Comment: appears it uses paper js, see here  http://paperjs.org/reference/point/#multiply which allows for point multiplication

Comment: @L.Lawliet, please see the referenced answer above.

Comment: Thanks a lot i get it now,  i did it same way and first time didn't work for me that is why i did this approach. Sorry for a late reply. Btw you are genius i would like to have someone to ask from time to time becuse I'm doing this all alone :)

Answer (score 0):

the above code is not vanilla javascript it is using paper.js which allows for point multiplication: http://paperjs.org/reference/point/#multiply

example from docs:

```
var firstPoint = new Point(5, 10);
var secondPoint = new Point(4, 2);
var result = firstPoint * secondPoint;
console.log(result); // {x: 20, y: 20}
```

Comment: I'm using it too. And i read the tutorials, doesn't work. I tried every single thing in tutorial to the dot. But only accessing object property and multiplying works for me.